Hide payment method for virtual products in Woocommerce
I am setting up a multi-seller store where some products are bookable, such as services, which are virtual products, I need to be able to restrict the cash on delivery method for these products.
I have tried a couple of solutions but none of them have worked, the payment method is still shown.
First solution tested:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'disable_payment_gateway_based_on_product_type' );
function disable_payment_gateway_based_on_product_type( $available_gateways ) {
    $cart = WC()->cart;
    
    if ( !is_null($cart) && !$cart->is_empty() ){
        foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $product = $cart_item['data'];
            if ( $product->is_type( 'virtual' ) ) { // Change 'virtual' to the product type you want to restrict
                unset( $available_gateways['cod'] ); // Disable COD for virtual products
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}

Second(adapted from a solution found here):
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'conditional_payment_gateways', 10, 1);
function conditional_payment_gateways( $available_gateways ) {
    // Not in backend (admin)
    if( is_admin() ) 
        return $available_gateways;

    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $prod_virtual = false;
        // Get the WC_Product object
        $product = wc_get_product($cart_item['product_id']);
        // Get the product types in cart (example)
        if($product->is_type('virtual')) $prod_virtual = true;
       
    }
    // Remove Cash on delivery (cod) payment gateway for virtual products
    if($prod_virtual)
        unset($available_gateways['cod']); // unset 'cod'
    

    return $available_gateways;
}

I am using Woocommerce 9.3.1

Use $product->is_virtual() vs $product->is_type('virtual')

Excellent, worked perfectly, thanks!!!
